# SQL error with custom query

Tags: php, database, functions, mysql, query

I'm trying to create a custom post query for sorting posts that have been voted "thumbs up".

I'm joining my custom "wp_post_votes" table (which stores the number of votes each post received) with the default "wp_posts" table and displaying posts `WHERE votes > 1`.

The WHERE cause is causing an SQL error. When I remove the `posts_where` filter I get no errors but all my posts are displayed regardless of their vote number.

```
    add_filter('posts_join', 'vote_join' );
    add_filter('posts_where', 'vote_where' );

    function vp_join( $join )
    {

      global $wpdb;

      if (isset($_GET['vote_sort'])) { //when visitor browses voted posts
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN wp_post_votes ON " . 
           $wpdb->posts . ".ID = wp_vote_posts.vote_post_id ";
      }

      return $join;
    }

    function vp_where( $where )
    {
      if (isset($_GET['vp_sort'])) {
        $where = "voted > 1";
       }

      return $where;
    }

//custom permalinks code follows...
```

The SQL error I get in index is..

> WordPress database error: [] SELECT
>   t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER
>   JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON
>   tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN
>   wp_term_relationships AS tr ON
>   tr.term_taxonomy_id =
>   tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy
>   IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN
>   (0) ORDER BY t.name ASC

..and in my sidebar I have a recent posts widget. In that I get via `$wpdb->show_errors();`

> WordPress database error: [You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'voted > 1 ORDER BY
>   wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5' at
>   line 1] SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
>   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN
>   wp_vote_posts ON wp_posts.ID =
>   wp_vote_posts.vote_post_id WHERE 1=1
>   voted > 1 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date
>   DESC LIMIT 0, 5

I noticed `WHERE 1=1 voted > 1`.. not sure if that's causing the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Is there a reason you really needed a separate table? Why not use custom fields *(postmeta?)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel the custom field table has too much data and will create too many rows for voting. My separate table is more clean and organized.

Comment: Are you logging votes, or just creating a running total?  If the former, I agree another table but  I'd still consider maintaining the running total in custom fields, even on a per-option basis so up to 5 custom fields per post if you are using a 1..5 rating. Or you could store in one custom field as an array, but they could could do a join across posts for all posts where vote=5, for example. Otherwise if you use SQL to count the votes each time you'll end up with a very poorly performing site *(I know this from specific experience related to a voting plugin I wrote.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
$where .= " AND voted > 1";
```

Other notes:

- instead of hardcoding table names you should use `$wpdb->prefix . 'post_votes'`;
- instead of checking in global `$_GET` you should declare your filters as accepting two arguments and code functions accordingly, these filters pass as second argument object that contains all of query data.

Like:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'vote_where', 10, 2 );

function vote_where( $where, $query ) {

    if( isset( $query->query_vars['vp_sort'] ) );
        $where .= ' AND voted > 1';

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rarst!! It works now :) I don't understand your second note. I have to check if the URL parameter exists to use the filter. How can I implement the two arguments you provided?

Comment: Your URL parameters are parsed and stored in query object, which you can access inside your function via passed `$query` variable in my example above. Just try `var_dump( $query );` to see everything that it contains, your custom arguments should be in there as well if used.

Comment: I'm very sorry Rarst, I still don't fully understand. Can you please share an example?

Comment: Updated answer with more written out example.

Comment: Ooh I see. Thanks! I tried the code, no errors.. but nothing happens. All posts are displayed regardless of the URL paramater

Comment: Well, hard to guess fot custom tables, etc. Just go through it step by step and check everything. You can also dump resulting SQL query to check if your modifications are applied, I think filter is `posts_request`.

Comment: @Rarst - Is `$query->query_vars->vp_sort` correct?  I thought `$query->query_vars` was an array, not an object?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel yeah, my mistake. :( Corrected code.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel thanks for pointing that out! The code works now :) but I don't understand what the `10, 2` stands for in add_filter. Can someone please explain?

Comment: @wpStudent - `10` is the *"priority"*, it determines which hooks run earlier and which run later. `10` is the default but if you made it `11` it would run after one that is set to `10`.  You need to specify the priority because, even though it has the same value as the default you must tell `add_action()` that `vote_where()` expects two (`2`) parameters: `$where` and `$query`; does that help?

Comment: @Rarst - Yep, easy mistake to make.

Comment: @ MikeSchinkel is definitely does! Thank you for sharing with me :) Things are making sense

Comment: After playing with the priorities I made the blog load faster!